How to style a div based on its returned value from database?
I have a table of cards with values from a database, floating on each card is a DIV that I'd like its background color to be red or green based on its value. This DIV has class tags2
Its value is retrieved from column status from table actors and is VARCHAR either "Retired" "Active" or it's cell is empty.
My code looks like this:
<tbody>

 <?php
   include_once("conn.php");
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM actors
   INNER JOIN actor_count ON actors.actor_id = actor_count.actor_id
   ORDER BY Full_Name";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 ?>

 <?php 
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>';
 ?>

 <div class="card">

   <a href="<?php echo $row["Profile_Link"]; ?>" >
   <div class="card_image">
     <img src="/location/<?php echo $row['Image_Title']; ?>"  alt="..." class="card_image">
   </div>
   
   <div class="card_body">
     <div class="card_body_line">
        <div class="name"><?php echo $row["Full_Name"];?></div>
        <div class="flag"><src="/location/<?php echo $row["flag"];?>"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="card_body_line" style="color:#888888">
       <div class="tags"><?php echo $row["DOB_Year"];?></div>
       <div class="tags">Movies (<?php echo $row["count"];?>)</div>
       <div class="tags"><?php echo $row["favourite"];?></div>
       <div class="tags"><?php echo $row["legend"];?></div>
       <div class="tags2" id="tags2"><?php echo $row["status"];?></div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </a>

<?php       
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '</td>';
?>
      
</div>  

<?php
}
?>

</tbody>


I've tried a few different JavaScript examples from online and can't seem to get it to work
I would like Red = Retired and Green = Active, if cell is empty apply no styling

Sounds like you need an IF or 2 or a SWITCH all in PHP


I've tried a few different JS examples

...I'm not sure why you'd want or need JavaScript for this. Just add a style tag to the div element and use PHP to inject a suitable  value for background-color into it depending on the value of $row["status"].
Super-basic example:
$statusColour = ""; 
if ($row["status"] == "Retired") { $statusColour = "red"; }
if ($row["status"] == "Active") {  $statusColour = "green"; }
.
.
.
<div class="tags2" id="tags2" style="background-color:<?php echo $statusColour; ?>">


Both if statements will produce error. There's an extra ) right before the ; } fragment. By the way, it can be written just like if ($row["status"] == "Retired") $statusColour = "red"; because if there's only one expression inside the if, then there's no need to wrap it with {}.

@KLASANGUI I've corrected the typo, thankyou. The { ... } brackets are just a matter of preference, of course. Everyone can choose to use them or not use them. This is just a basic example for illustration, so I don't think we need to get hung up on that kind of stylistic opinion.

You're welcome. I'm not actually hung up on that and I agree with you indeed. I just took the opportunity to teach/remind you that. That's why "By the way" is there.

Thanks for the solution. Upvoted as it works well. On the JS piece, google sent me that route and I recall doing something with JS & onclick (so it kinda made sense? I'm a noob hobbyist). After a nights sleep I realized my brain fart and mistake, my column 'status' only ever has two values, Retired or Active, so I simply created two corresponding CSS classes and replaced div=tags2 with div=$row[status]. Not clean for those with excess-CSS phobia but it works.

@BoggyB using CSS classes makes sense for this just as much as using an inline style. Some would say it's cleaner as then all the style rules are in one place, and/or you can re-use it for different purposes. And if you ever change the colour scheme, you only have to change it once, and not go hunting around the code for it. So don't worry about "excess" CSS, IMHO! Glad you found an approach which works for you
